# KeychainWrapper in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I user KeychainWrapper to store user login and password in my app after user is logged in.

KeychainWrapper is https://github.com/jrendel/SwiftKeychainWrapper/blob/master/SwiftKeychainWrapper/KeychainWrapper.swift

To save data i use:

```
let saveLogin: Bool = KeychainWrapper.setString("\(Login)", forKey: "Login")
let savePass: Bool = KeychainWrapper.setString("\(Pass)", forKey: "Pass")
```

To read data i use:

```
Login = KeychainWrapper.stringForKey("Login")?
Pass = KeychainWrapper.stringForKey("Pass")?
```

But when i exit app and close it - this variables are nil. What is wrong?

Comment: Can you add your KeychainWrapper initialization please

Comment: @TheSD i updated question

Comment: When you read data does it exist before closing the app?

Comment: Yes, data is saving properly.